# Rank of a block vecor

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the $n\times n$ block matrix of the form
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} A_1 \\ A_2 \\ \vdots \\ A_k \end{pmatrix}$$
where $A_i$ is a $s_i\times n$ matrix and $s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_k=n$. Can we get any information about $rank(A)$ based on the structures of $A_i$?

Comment: Do these $A_i$ have any additional structure? Any answer would depend on such extra information.

Comment: $A_i$ has a particular structure that it comes from multiplication of three matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information from each $A_i$

$$rank(A) \geq \max_{i=1..n}rank(A_i)$$

Proving this fact is straightforward: Let $A_i$ have rank $r$. Then $A_i$ has $r$ linearly independent rows. But every row in $A_i$ is a row in $A$, therefore $rank(A) \geq r$.  The condition $_1+_2+..+_=$ is not even needed ($A$ does not have to be a square matrix)

We can't get the strict inequality (think of the case where each $A_i$ is a null matrix)